# Adding a settimeout inside if statement to update the boolean value

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am setting a boolean a value on input keyup action. I have a logic to check my input value according to that I am setting that boolean value. In else condition I want make my boolean true and then false after one second. I want it to be true just for one second. I am using this boolean in HTML to add a class (to set a background, it should fade away after 1 sec). But my below logic is not working. Please help me.

HTML

```
<input
    type="text"
    data-ng-class="{'inputBgChange': controller.firstAmountUpdated}"
    ng-keyup="controller.myFunction()"
>
```

CSS

```
.inputBgChange {background-color: red;}
```

JS

```
myFunction() {
    const diffBeforeUpdate = this.secondAmount - this.firstAmount;
    const diffAfterUpdate = this.secondAmount - this.prevfirstAmount;
    if((diffBeforeUpdate >= 50 && diffAfterUpdate >= 50) || this.secondAmount === '')  {
        this.firstAmount = this.prevfirstAmount;
        this.firstAmountUpdated = false;
    } else {
        this.firstAmount = parseInt(this.secondAmount) - 50;
        this.firstAmount >= 0 ? this.firstAmountUpdated = true : this.firstAmountUpdated = false;
        setTimeout(() => this.firstAmountUpdated = false
        , 1000);

    }
}
```

`firstAmountUpdated` is the boolean I want to update in setTimeout.

Comment: I think you may have a scoping issue here, `this` may very well refer to the function object rather than your overall scope

Comment: `I am using this boolean in HTML to add a class (to set a background, it should fade away after 1 sec)` - sounds like it can be solved with CSS

Answer (score 0):

I think Jaxi is correct.

You can test the `this` context by checking it when the function run after the timeout:

```
setTimeout(
 () => {
    console.log(this);
    this.firstAmountUpdated = false;
 }
, 1000);
```

If you get `undefined`, you can bind the function beforehand:

```
    const timeoutFunc = () => this.firstAmountUpdated = false;
    setTimeout(timeoutFunc.bind(this), 1000);
```

Comment: I tried but it is not going inside the settimeout. I have set this.firstAmountUpdated = false in my class constructor.

Comment: So do the binding to the instance you've created using that class.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `setTimeout`, use the AngularJS $timeout service:

```
myFunction() {
    const diffBeforeUpdate = this.secondAmount - this.firstAmount;
    const diffAfterUpdate = this.secondAmount - this.prevfirstAmount;
    if((diffBeforeUpdate >= 50 && diffAfterUpdate >= 50) || this.secondAmount === '')  {
        this.firstAmount = this.prevfirstAmount;
        this.firstAmountUpdated = false;
    } else {
        this.firstAmount = parseInt(this.secondAmount) - 50;
        this.firstAmount >= 0 ? this.firstAmountUpdated = true : this.firstAmountUpdated = false;
        ̶s̶e̶t̶T̶i̶m̶e̶o̶u̶t̶(̶(̶)̶ ̶=̶>̶ ̶t̶h̶i̶s̶.̶f̶i̶r̶s̶t̶A̶m̶o̶u̶n̶t̶U̶p̶d̶a̶t̶e̶d̶ ̶=̶ ̶f̶a̶l̶s̶e̶
        this.$timeout(() => this.firstAmountUpdated = false
        , 1000);    
    }
}
```

AngularJS modifies the normal JavaScript flow by providing its own event processing loop. This splits the JavaScript into classical and AngularJS execution context. Only operations which are applied in the AngularJS execution context will benefit from AngularJS data-binding, exception handling, property watching, etc.

The $timeout service integrates the `setTimeout` method with the AngularJS framework and its digest cycle.

For more information, see

- [AngularJS $timeout Service API Reference](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$timeout)